# What is the issue with passing an (iterator) value into a closure (expected type parameter `I`, found struct `std::slice::Iter`)?

Tags: rust

I would like to understand the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/tabs.rs:70:44
   |
43 | fn detab_go<'a, I, R, W>(
   |                 - this type parameter
...
70 |                         f_out, bytes_iter, buf_iter,
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `I`, found struct `std::slice::Iter`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `I`
                      found struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, u8>`
```

The code that causes the error looks like this (expanded from a macro I've been working on):

```
fn detab_go<'a, I, R, W>(
    f_out: &mut W,
    bytes_iter: BytesIter<R>,
    buf_iter: I,
    tab_pos_last: usize,
) -> Result<(), Error>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a u8>,
    R: Read,
    W: Write,
{
    tailcall::trampoline::run_res(
        #[inline(always)]
        |(f_out, mut bytes_iter, mut buf_iter, tab_pos_last)| {
            Ok(tailcall::trampoline::Finish({
                match buf_iter.next() {
                    Some(byte) => {
                        if !is_tab_or_newline(*byte) {
                            write_u8(f_out, *byte)?;
                        }
                        return Ok(tailcall::trampoline::Recurse((
                            f_out, bytes_iter, buf_iter, 1,
                        )));
                    }
                    None => match bytes_iter.next() {
                        Some(buf_new) => {
                            let buf_test: Vec<u8> = buf_new?;
                            let buf_iter = buf_test.iter();
                            return Ok(tailcall::trampoline::Recurse((
                                f_out, bytes_iter, buf_iter, 1,
                            )));
                        }
                        None => Ok(()),
                    },
                }
            }))
        },
        (f_out, bytes_iter, buf_iter, tab_pos_last),
    )
}
```

The non-macro-expanded code does not cause a compile error. It should have the same meaning as the macro-expanded code (though slightly different run-time characteristics), and looks like:

```
fn detab_go<'a, I, R, W>(
    f_out: &mut W,
    mut bytes_iter: BytesIter<R>,
    mut buf_iter: I,
    tab_pos_last: usize,
) -> Result<(), Error>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a u8>,
    R: Read,
    W: Write,
{
    match buf_iter.next() {
        Some(byte) => {
            if !is_tab_or_newline(*byte) {
                write_u8(f_out, *byte)?;
            }
            detab_go(
                f_out, bytes_iter, buf_iter,
                /*&tab_pos_new*/ /*todo!() */ 1,
            )
        }
        None => {
            match bytes_iter.next() {
                Some(buf_new) => {
                    let buf_test: Vec<u8> = buf_new?;
                    let buf_iter = buf_test.iter(); //shadow
                    detab_go(
                        f_out, bytes_iter, buf_iter,
                        /*&tab_pos_new*/ /*todo!()*/ 1,
                    )
                }
                None => Ok(()), /* Finished */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The trampoline is expecting *exactly* the same types as its initial values to recurse with. But you're recursing with a `slice::Iter` when its expecting an `I`. To make the trampoline accept both, you'll need to pass it as a trait object like `Box<Iterator<Item = &'a u8>>`. Though without testing it for myself, you'll probably have trouble matching lifetimes. So you'd have to use `.cloned()` and `.into_iter()` on top of `Box`s to get them in line.

Comment: Its hard to give a concrete answer due to missing crates, imports, types (`BytesIter`), and functions (`is_tab_or_newline` and `write_u8`). Please include them, even as stubs. Also, I can't find `tailcall::trampoline::run_res`, only [`tailcall::trampoline::run`](https://docs.rs/tailcall/0.1.4/tailcall/trampoline/fn.run.html).

Comment: I can perhaps do a bit better, which is to point to the branch and commit in question; well, the commit includes the solution proposed by @phimuemue): https://github.com/bbarker/SoftwareTools/tree/detab_go ; commit bbb2381

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difference lies in the kind of recursion: Directly calling `detab_go` recursively allows the commpiler to see that `detab_go` accepts an arbitrary `Iterator<Item=u8>`, whereas the `trampoline` version seems to fix `I` -- disallowing different types as input.

Maybe it helps to make `detab_go` accept a `std::slice::Iter<'_, u8>` instead of a generic `Iterator`.

Comment: Yes, that seemed to fix the issue; it still works with the non-macro code, and now I have a new, different error from the macro-expanded code related to borrows.